# Having trouble with an SQL CE nested query

Tags: sql, nested, sql-server-ce

Okay, I've been using MySQL for so long that I'd forgotten how much easier it is to use than MS SQL. I'm having trouble with what should be a simple nested query.

I have two tables, groups and group_members.

I'm trying to select data from groups and a count of records from group_members using groups.id as a subquery parameter.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT id AS [Group ID],
       type,
       name,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM group_members WHERE (group_id = [Group ID]) AND (paid = 1)) + '/' + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM group_members WHERE (group_id = [Group ID]))
FROM groups
```

For each group this would show me the type, the name, and how many have paid in fractional form (i.e. '6/10').

When I try using this query in SQL CE I get an error: "There was an error parsing the query."

If I run the queries separately they work fine, so I'm guessing there is an issue with the way SQL CE handles nested queries vs. MySQL's method.

Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I was finally able to accomplish this by doing a left join of the subqueries instead of calling them in the master SELECT statement.

Here is the working query:

```
SELECT grps.group_name,
         CASE
              WHEN members1.paid_count IS NULL
                  THEN 0
              ELSE members1.paid_count
         END AS paid,
         CASE
              WHEN members2.member_count IS NULL
                  THEN 0
              ELSE members2.member_count
         END AS total_members
FROM groups AS grps
LEFT JOIN (SELECT group_id, COUNT(id) AS paid_count FROM group_members WHERE paid = 1 GROUP BY group_id) AS members1 ON grps.id = members1.group_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT group_id, COUNT(id) AS member_count FROM group_members GROUP BY group_id) AS members2 ON grps.id = members2.group_id
```